# File.Copy versus read and write in C#

Tags: c#

I have to implement a functionality where file needs to be copied from one location and should be pasted in another location(some folder in other drive on same server).

I have two options

```
1. Implement file.copy functionality.
2. Read the file using StreamReader and the create and write  destination file.
```

Can anybody please confim which option would be better and performance wise and less prone to errors and copy failures.

Thanks

Comment: What would be you own hypothesis

Comment: If option 2 was better, why would Microsoft not **use it as the implementation of `File.Copy`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see with Reflector, File.Copy use native windows methods to create a duplicate. I think it will be faster that read bytes from one stream and write to another one.

```
public static void Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
    if (sourceFileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sourceFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
    }
    if (destFileName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("destFileName", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentNull_FileName"));
    }
    if (sourceFileName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "sourceFileName");
    }
    if (destFileName.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyFileName"), "destFileName");
    }
    InternalCopy(sourceFileName, destFileName, false, true);
}
```

And content of InternalCopy method is:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
internal static string InternalCopy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, bool overwrite, bool checkHost)
{
    string fullPathInternal = Path.GetFullPathInternal(sourceFileName);
    string dst = Path.GetFullPathInternal(destFileName);
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, new string[] { fullPathInternal }, false, false).Demand();
    new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, new string[] { dst }, false, false).Demand();
    if (!Win32Native.CopyFile(fullPathInternal, dst, !overwrite))
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        string maybeFullPath = destFileName;
        if (errorCode != 80)
        {
            using (SafeFileHandle handle = Win32Native.UnsafeCreateFile(fullPathInternal, -2147483648, FileShare.Read, null, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                if (handle.IsInvalid)
                {
                    maybeFullPath = sourceFileName;
                }
            }
            if ((errorCode == 5) && Directory.InternalExists(dst))
            {
                throw new IOException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_FileIsDirectory_Name", new object[] { destFileName }), 5, dst);
            }
        }
        __Error.WinIOError(errorCode, maybeFullPath);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go with 1st option.
Because its a inbuilt function and will use CPU rather then Memory

StreamReader will use Memory which is should be avoided when you have large files. However buffering can also be implemented in this.

Answer (score 0):

File.Copy will do the job. Wouldn't go to StreamReader with say FileStream, unless I wanted to do say a progress bar.