# FileInfo.CopyTo how to detect overwrite

Tags: c#

```
file.CopyTo(destinationFullName , true);

if (destinationFullName == file.FullName) {
      logTrace(TraceEventType.Information, "Overwritten file " + file.FullName + " with " + destinationFullName);
 }
```

Is there a good way to detect if a file is being overwritten instead of manually comparing file name of source and destination.  I was like to log a message if CopyTo overwrites a file.

Comment: **Hint:** [FileInfo.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.exists?view=net-5.0). Before `.CopyTo`.

Comment: But realize that there's a race condition lurking in there (pretty much an unavoidable race condition).

Comment: No, FileInfo.Exists is not good enough.

Comment: If you don't want to use FileExists before copy, there is no WinAPI (in the case of Windows) to copy a file and get a value indicating whether the file was created new or was overwritten, as I know. Therefore, you need to create your own method using for example a stream, perhaps, which will be like: `FileCopyResult CopyFile(string source, string target, bool overwrite);` where `FileCopyResult` can be `{Created, Overwritted}` and you will raise any standard exceptions. [Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044629/) • [Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982277/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to check if the file exists before you try to copy, you could use the `File.Copy()` method where it says right in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_) that overwriting a file is not allowed:

> Copies an existing file to a new file. Overwriting a file of the same name is not allowed.
>
> ...
>
> **IOException**
> destFileName exists.

So you could put the Copy in a try, and then catch an `IOException` that would indicate that the file already exists. See the link I pasted for more information.

I am sure you have a good reason for not wanting to check for the existence of the file in advance. I don't normally recommend using a try catch block like this though.

Comment: fwiw, `File.Exists()` is [kind of bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265958/3043), and this is the correct way to do it :)

Comment: I see your point. The file system can be tricky and unpredictable, especially on a network with multiple users.

Comment: I do want to overwrite the file though I just want to make a note if that happens.  So are you saying to copy again if exception triggers?

Comment: You could do that from the catch block. If your code goes into the catch block with a destFileName exists exception, you could then log it and then overwrite the file.